# android Json show only last item

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have one problem: my json parser shows only the last item! But at Logcat I see all items! 
Can you help me?

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);      
      Log.d("Log", result.toString());
      JSONObject jsn = result;
      try {
        JSONArray jarray = jsn.getJSONArray("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsno = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+jsno.getString("link")+"\">"+jsno.getString("title")+"</a>"));
            cat.setText(jsno.getString("category"));
            date.setText(jsno.getString("pubDate"));
            desc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            desc.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("charset=UTF-8");             desc.loadData(jsno.getString("description"), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "utf-8");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How are you displaying the items?  You seem to set the same textviews each time in the loop, therefore you will only see the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you iterate through the JSON array of `item` elements, you're setting the fields on the same `title`, `cat` and `date` objects on each iteration. This is why only the last item is 'showing'.

You need to create a new object for each `JSONObject(i)` and store it somewhere.